# Remove Dashboard button from menu in my account page - WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I don't need the dashboard tab in woocommerce account page. So, how can I remove the Dashboard button from the menu in my account page - WooCommerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires 2 different hooked functions:

- The first function will remove the first my account menu item (which is the dashboard).
- The second function will redirect the default my account dashboard page to the first my account endpoint.

The code:

```
// Remove the first menu item (the dashboard)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'account_menu_items_callback' );
function account_menu_items_callback( $items ) {
    foreach( $items as $key => $item ) {
        unset($items[$key]);
        break;
    }
    return $items;
}

// Redirect default my account dashboard to the first my account enpoint (after dashboard)
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'template_redirect_callback' );
function template_redirect_callback() {
    if( is_account_page() && is_user_logged_in() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ){
        $first_myaccount_endpoint = 'orders';
        wp_redirect( wc_get_account_endpoint_url( $first_myaccount_endpoint ) );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme)*. Tested and works.